# Add paragraph breaks in javascript variable of text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a variable called `text` that has a number of strings that are meant to be paragraphs that are separated by <br><br>.

However, my code is not displaying the breaks.

Below is my minimally working code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="content">
        <p id="textParagraph" style="display: none"></p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
    // Initialize data structures and variables
    var wordDictionary = {};         // Dictionary to store words
        var selectedWords = {};          // Currently selected words
        var isMouseDown = false;         // Flag for mouse state
        var currentColor = '';           // Current highlight color
        var usedColors = new Set();      // Set of used colors
        // Available highlight colors
        var availableColors = ["yellow", "red", "blue", "green", "orange"]; 
        var highlights = {};             // Store highlighted words for each event
        var eventCounter = 0;            // Counter for events

        var text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cu eum eros vitae persequeris, laudem possit nam ex. \
        Labore eloquentiam per an. Sit ex omnesque interpretaris, habeo tantas eos ad, ea eos ludus inciderint. \
        Facete tritani pro ei, vim evertitur liberavisse ex. Ridens indoctum duo cu, est utamur aliquando expetendis ne. <br><br>\
        \n\
        Cum nusquam definiebas ex, id esse neglegentur cum, eu libris bonorum volumus vis. \
        Ius et quis omnis graeco, no his nullam perpetua dissentiet. \
        No vix possim scripserit consequuntur, te mnesarchum philosophia sed. \
        Ne mea putent iudicabit, in eam ipsum viris dicunt. Eum amet accommodare ex, sint malis adversarium at qui.";

        var textParagraph = document.getElementById("textParagraph");
        textParagraph.textContent = text;

         // Execute when the window is loaded
         window.onload = function () {
            var contentDiv = document.getElementById('content');
            var text = contentDiv.textContent.trim();
            var words = text.split(/\s+/);

            // Populate wordDictionary with words and create span elements for each word
            for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                wordDictionary[i] = words[i];
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                var wordElement = document.createElement('span');
                wordElement.textContent = words[i] + ' ';
                wordElement.dataset.index = i;
                wordElement.addEventListener('mousedown', handleMouseDown);
                contentDiv.appendChild(wordElement);
            }

            // Add mouseup event listener for handling mouse up events
            document.addEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp);
        };
        // Function to get a random highlight color
        function getRandomColor() {
            if (availableColors.length === 0) {
                availableColors = [...usedColors];
                usedColors.clear();
            }

            var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * availableColors.length);
            var color = availableColors.splice(randomIndex, 1)[0];
            usedColors.add(color);
            return color;
        }

        // Function to handle mouse down event on words
        function handleMouseDown(event) {
            isMouseDown = true;
            var index = event.target.dataset.index;
            var word = event.target.textContent.trim();

            if (!isHighlighted(index)) {
                selectedWords = {};
                selectedWords.startIndex = index;
                selectedWords.endIndex = index;

                selectedWords[index] = word;
                currentColor = getRandomColor();
                event.target.style.backgroundColor = currentColor;

                event.preventDefault();

                document.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
            }
        }

        // Function to handle mouse up event
        function handleMouseUp(event) {
            if (isMouseDown) {
                document.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
                var highlightedWords = {};

                for (var index in selectedWords) {
                    if (index !== 'startIndex' && index !== 'endIndex') {
                        highlightedWords[index] = selectedWords[index];
                    }
                }

                eventCounter++;
                highlights[eventCounter] = highlightedWords;
                console.log(highlights);
            }

            isMouseDown = false;
        }

        // Function to handle mouse move event (word selection)
        function handleMouseMove(event) {
            if (isMouseDown) {
                var currentIndex = event.target.dataset.index;
                var startIndex = selectedWords.startIndex;
                var endIndex = selectedWords.endIndex;
                var contentDiv = document.getElementById('content');

                var newStartIndex = Math.min(startIndex, currentIndex);
                var newEndIndex = Math.max(endIndex, currentIndex);

                clearPreviousSelection();

                for (var i = newStartIndex; i <= newEndIndex; i++) {
                    selectedWords[i] = wordDictionary[i];
                }

                for (var i = newStartIndex + 1; i <= newEndIndex + 1; i++) {
                    contentDiv.children[i].style.backgroundColor = currentColor;
                }

                selectedWords.startIndex = newStartIndex;
                selectedWords.endIndex = newEndIndex;
            }
        }

        // Function to clear previously selected words
        function clearPreviousSelection() {
            var contentDiv = document.getElementById('content');

            for (var i in selectedWords) {
                if (i !== 'startIndex' && i !== 'endIndex') {
                    contentDiv.children[i].style.backgroundColor = '';
                    delete selectedWords[i];
                }
            }
        }

        // Function to check if a word is already highlighted
        function isHighlighted(index) {
            for (var eventKey in highlights) {
                var highlightedWords = highlights[eventKey];

                for (var wordIndex in highlightedWords) {
                    if (wordIndex === index) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }

            return false;
        }

        // Function to clear all selections and reset
        function clearSelections() {
            var contentDiv = document.getElementById('content');
            var wordElements = contentDiv.getElementsByTagName('span');

            for (var i = 0; i < wordElements.length; i++) {
                wordElements[i].style.backgroundColor = '';
            }

            highlights = {};
            eventCounter = 0;
        }

        // Function to undo the last selection
        function undoSelection() {
            if (eventCounter > 0) {
                var lastHighlight = highlights[eventCounter];

                for (var index in lastHighlight) {
                    var wordIndex = parseInt(index);
                    var contentDiv = document.getElementById('content');

                    if (!isNaN(wordIndex)) {
                        contentDiv.children[wordIndex + 1].style.backgroundColor = '';
                    }
                }

                delete highlights[eventCounter];
                eventCounter--;
            }
        }

        // Add event listeners to the clear and undo buttons
        document.getElementById("removeHighlight").addEventListener("click", clearSelections);
        document.getElementById("undoHighlight").addEventListener("click", undoSelection);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: DO use `<br>`,  but then don't use `textParagraph.textContent`, use `textParagraph.innerHTML` - also, for simpler writing, use template literal strings, so you won't have to escape newlines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to preserve the paragraph breaks in your text variable, you should use `innerHTML` instead of `textContent` as textContent treats everything as plain text while `innerHTML` treats the content as HTML

So, instead of using `textParagraph.textContent = text;`, try using `textParagraph.innerHTML = text;`

Comment: Minor comment; It's not `textparagraph` that is being rendered out, it's `wordElement` that he should set to `InnerHTML` and then use `<br>` tags to force linebreaks. In the top of the code you can see that `textparagraph` is set to `style="display: none"`.

Comment: Thank you for highlighting. Looks like the question has been edited.

Answer (score -1):

you can also use insertAdjacentHTML() method

more information [Element: insertAdjacentHTML() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)